# Cannot GET / error in browser (nodejs express) while running this script

Tags: node.js, express

```
const express=require('express')
const path=require('path')

const app=express()

app.use(function(req,res,next){
console.log('hello')
next()
```

})

```
app.get('/signup',function(req,res,next){
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'signup.html'))
next()
```

})

```
app.get(function(req,res){
console.log('end')
```

})

```
app.post('/signup',function (req,res){
res.send('hhhhh')

})

app.listen(300,function(){

console.log('server started')
```

Cannot GET /  error  in browser (nodejs express) while running this script
please help me...

Comment: What is your expectation?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I run above code and execute in browser but browser showing this error 'Cannot GET/'

Comment: @hoangdv My expectation is show login page this html page signup.html

Comment: Its solved its my mistake sorry guys i forget change this code .app.get (function (req, res)
console.log ('end'), to
 this code.app.use (function (req, res)
console.log ('end')